# Web scraping error: exceptions.MemoryError

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to download data from gsmarena. A sample code to download HTC one me spec is from the following site: "http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_me-7275.php" as mentioned below.

The data on the website is classified in form of tables and table rows. 
The data is of the format:

```
table header > td[@class='ttl'] > td[@class='nfo']
```

Items.py file:

```
import scrapy

class gsmArenaDataItem(scrapy.Item):
    phoneName = scrapy.Field()
    phoneDetails = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Spider file:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Spider
from gsmarena_data.items import gsmArenaDataItem

class testSpider(Spider):
    name = "mobile_test"
    allowed_domains = ["gsmarena.com"]
    start_urls = ('http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one_me-7275.php',)

    def parse(self, response):
        # extract whatever stuffs you want and yield items here
        hxs = Selector(response)
        phone = gsmArenaDataItem()
        tableRows = hxs.css("div#specs-list table")
        for tableRows in tableRows:
            phone['phoneName'] = tableRows.xpath(".//th/text()").extract()[0]
            for ttl in tableRows.xpath(".//td[@class='ttl']"):
                ttl_value = " ".join(ttl.xpath(".//text()").extract())
                nfo_value = " ".join(ttl.xpath("following-sibling::td[@class='nfo']//text()").extract())
                colonSign = ": "
                commaSign = ", "
                seq = [ttl_value, colonSign, nfo_value, commaSign]
                seq = seq.join(seq)
        phone['phoneDetails'] = seq
        yield phone
```

However, the code is giving me error while running:

```
File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\gsmarena_data\gsmarena_data\spiders\test.py", line 26, in parse
            sequenceNew = sequenceNew.join(seq)
        exceptions.MemoryError:
```

The idea is to get the data in the following format:

table row header: respective data, table row header: respective data, ....

the same is illustrated below:

```
Network Technology: GSM / HSPA / LTE, Network 2G bands: GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 - SIM 1 & SIM 2, Battery Stand-by: Up to 598 h (2G) / Up to 626 h (3G), Battery Talk time: Up to 23 h (2G) / Up to 13 h (3G),
```

**Update 1:**

Using the code as suggested by @alecxe:

```
def parse(self, response):
        # extract whatever stuffs you want and yield items here
        phone = gsmArenaDataItem()
        details = []

        for tableRows in response.css("div#specs-list table"):
            phone['phoneName'] = tableRows.xpath(".//th/text()").extract()[0]
            for ttl in tableRows.xpath(".//td[@class='ttl']"):
                ttl_value = " ".join(ttl.xpath(".//text()").extract())
                nfo_value = " ".join(ttl.xpath("following-sibling::td[@class='nfo']//text()").extract())
                details.append('{title}: {info}'.format(title=ttl_value, info=nfo_value))
        phone['phoneDetails'] = ", ".join(details)
        yield phone
```

Gives the error:

```
File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\gsmarena_data\gsmarena_data\spiders\test.py", line 22, in parse
details.append('{title}: {info}'.format(title=ttl_value, info=nfo_value))
exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the phone details in the list and `join()` them after the loop:

```
def parse(self, response):
    phone = gsmArenaDataItem()
    details = []

    for tableRows in response.css("div#specs-list table"):
        phone['phoneName'] = tableRows.xpath(".//th/text()").extract()[0]
        for ttl in tableRows.xpath(".//td[@class='ttl']"):
            ttl_value = " ".join(ttl.xpath(".//text()").extract())
            nfo_value = " ".join(ttl.xpath("following-sibling::td[@class='nfo']//text()").extract())
            details.append('{title}: {info}'.format(title=ttl_value.encode("utf-8"), info=nfo_value.encode("utf-8")))

    phone['phoneDetails'] = ", ".join(details)
    yield phone
```

Comment: It is giving the following error:
          File "C:\Users\ajhavery\Desktop\gsmarena_data\gsmarena_data\spiders\te
st.py", line 22, in parse
            details.append('{title}: {info}'.format(title=ttl_value, info=nfo_va
lue))
        exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x
a0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @ajhavery okay, how about now?